# More efficient way to get diagonal length per coordinate

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, diagonal

I have an array of x and y values (coordinates) representing matches and for each of these x,y's I want to know the length of the diagonal it is part of. For example let's take these coordinates

**Data description**

```
coords = np.asarray([[0,0], [0,7], [1,1], [1,6], [2,2], [2,5], [3,3],[3,4], [4,4]])
# [[0 0]
#  [0 7]
#  [1 1]
#  [1 6]
#  [2 2]
#  [2 5]
#  [3 3]
#  [3 4]
#  [4 4]]
```

We can transform it to a matrix but this is *too inefficient* in my case with enermous tables (for instance, scipy [`todia()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.todia.html#scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.todia) will throw an inefficient warning; see below). Anyway let's make the matrix to make the problem more clear:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

**Goal**
Looking at the table above we see two diagonals (or one diagonal and one antidiagonal). For each position of the diagonal I want to know the length of the diagonal it is part of, so a table like this:

```
# x, y, diag length
[[0 0 5]
 [1 1 5]
 [2 2 5]
 [3 3 5]
 [4 4 5]
 [3 4 4]
 [2 5 4]
 [1 6 4]
 [0 7 4]]
```

**Inefficient solution**
I figured I could represent this data in a [sparse scipy matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) while this gives the desired result transforming the sparse matrix to a diagonal coordinate matrix is already [inefficient for 100 diagonals](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f2ec91c4908f9d67b5445fbfacce7f47518b35d1/scipy/sparse/coo.py#L376-L379) let alone for the thousands I have.

```
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix, coo_matrix
coords = np.asarray([[0,0], [0,7], [1,1], [1,6], [2,2], [2,5], [3,3],[3,4], [4,4]])

# Create the scipy coord matrix
x = coords[:,0]
y = coords[:,1]
tot_elem = coords.shape[0]*2
data = np.repeat(1, len(x))
co_mat = coo_matrix( (data, (x, y)), shape=(max(x)+1, max(y)+1))

# Get the diagonal matrix
dia_mat = dia_matrix(co_mat).tocoo()
diag_coords = np.column_stack((dia_mat.row, dia_mat.col))

# Get the consecutive values to put them to lengths
difs = np.diff(diag_coords[:, 1])
cuts = [0] + list(np.where(difs != 1)[0] + 1) + [diag_coords.shape[0]]
sizes = np.diff(cuts)
sizes = np.repeat(sizes, sizes)

# Combine with the original coords
dia_sizes = np.column_stack((dia_mat.row, dia_mat.col, sizes))
print(dia_sizes)
```

**Just realized a coordinate can be part of both a diagonal and antidiagonal, in this case I can report both or only report the length of the longest diagonal - which my solution does not take care of :(*

**EDIT:** **More efficient solution**

Looking at the todia() code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/701ffcc8a6f04509d115aac5e5681c538b5265a2/scipy/sparse/coo.py#L422-L428) I noticed they use a smart trick to see if points are on a diagonal, namely `x-y` should be the same for points on the same diagonal. However, this is not true for the anti-diagonal. So I assume the opposite, `x + y` does give us poinst on the same antidiagonal. Using this I came up with the code which already is much faster than using scipy.

```
import numpy as np

coords = np.asarray([[0,0], [0,7], [1,1], [1,6], [2,2], [2,5], [3,3],[3,4], [4,4]])
x = coords[:,0]
y = coords[:,1]

# Get the diagonal (inspired by scripy todia code)
ks1 = y - x

# Unlike scipy, I think we can do the same by summing to get the anti-diagonal
ks2 = y + x

# Sort these to get the groups in the same diagonal
idx = np.argsort(ks1)
anti_idx = np.argsort(ks2)

def get_dia_len(arr,ori):
    sizes = np.diff([0] + list(np.where(np.diff(arr)!= ori)[0] + 1) + [arr.shape[0]])
    size_arr = np.repeat(sizes, sizes)
    return size_arr

# Get the diagonal lengths, i.e. cut at changing values and get the gaps between them
norm_sizes = get_dia_len(x[idx],1)
anti_sizes = get_dia_len(y[anti_idx],-1)

# Gather this in a table
norm = np.column_stack([x[idx], y[idx], norm_sizes])
anti = np.column_stack([x[anti_idx], y[anti_idx], anti_sizes])
dia_coord = np.concatenate((norm, anti))

# We only have a diagonal when we have >1 value
dia_coord = dia_coord[dia_coord[:, -1] > 1]
print(dia_coord)
```

Have been bending my head around this for a while and curious to see if someone has a smart way to solve this :)

Comment: What if you had points `[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]` - would they form a "diagonal"?

Comment: @Mortz thanks for the question, no that would be a straight line down, not diagonally i.e. 45°

Comment: make it clear(er) that you are using `scipy.sparse`.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the heads up, forgot to mention the import as well - edited it

Comment: How long is the list of coords? What are the min and max values of x and y?

Comment: `dia_mat = dia_matrix(co_mat).tocoo()` - what does this do for you?  Isn't this the same as `dia_matrix` which you already have?  You mention using `todia`, but I don't see that in the code?

Comment: OK, looking further I see that going the `dia_matrix` sorts the `row/col` values differently.  The one diagonal is grouped together, but the anti-diagonal is not.  A good answer (or at least what I try to present) shows intermediate steps and explains what happens.  Hopefully then people can read it and understand, without actually running the code themselves.  I think your "inefficient solution" should do the same.  Otherwise we (the readers) are left "running" the code in our heads, and making wrong deductions.

Comment: @hpaulj Exactly! I edited my question with another solution I came up with, much faster than the other one already and this tackles the diagonal/anti-diagonal problem scipy has you mentioned. Will add more description when I'm free later today

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to loop through the coordinates and construct **45 degree** lines through each point (assuming that's what "diagonal" means), and then remove from the `coords` list any points that lie on this line -

This function computes points on the **45 degree** line of the fixed point and returns only those points which are on the `coords` list

```
coords = [[0,0], [0,7], [1,1], [1,6], [2,2], [2,5], [3,3],[3,4], [4,4]]
coords = [tuple(_) for _ in coords]

def get_y(x, fixed_point, allowed_slopes=(1, -1), coords=coords.copy()):
    coords = [tuple(_) for _ in coords]
    x_fixed, y_fixed = fixed_point
    possible_y = [y_fixed + slope*(x - x_fixed) for slope in allowed_slopes]
    possible_coords = [(x, y) for y in possible_y]
    available_coords = list(set(possible_coords) & set(coords))
    return available_coords
print(get_y(1, (0,0)))
#[(1, 1)]
print(get_y(6, (0,0)))
#[] because (6, 6) is not on coords
```

And then we can loop through `coords` while removing all points that are on the same line. Using the `list.pop` ensures that we don't have to unnecessarily compute diagonals multiple times for the same group of points

```
idx = 0
grouped_points = list()
while coords:
    group = list()
    fixed_point = coords.pop()
    print(f'fixed_point is now {fixed_point}')
    group.append(fixed_point)
    print(f'group is now {group}')
    available_x = set([x for (x, y) in coords])
    print(f'available_x is now {available_x}')
    for x in available_x:
        pt, *_ = get_y(x, fixed_point)
        print(f'pt is now {pt}')
        if pt and pt in coords:
            group.append(pt)
            coords.remove(pt)
        print(f'coords is now {coords}')
        print(f'group is now {group}')
    print(idx, group, sep='\t')
    grouped_points.append(group)
    idx += 1
```

And then append the lengths to the output to get the desired result

```
grouped_points = [(*pt, len(group)) for group in grouped_points for pt in group]
print(*grouped_points, sep='\n')
#(4, 4, 5)
#(0, 0, 5)
#(1, 1, 5)
#(2, 2, 5)
#(3, 3, 5)
#(3, 4, 4)
#(0, 7, 4)
#(1, 6, 4)
#(2, 5, 4)
```

Timing this using `timeit` shows that this solution is about 10X faster for this set of `coords`